# Can't set Content-type to Google Storage with the Google PHP Client

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I'm using [google-api-php-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/)

Here's the bit where I upload a .jpg image.

```
$postbody = array("data" => $imgData);
$gso = new Google_StorageObject();

$gso->setName($imageName);
$contentType = 'image/jpg';
$gso->setContentType($contentType);
$resp = $objects->insert('bucket-name', $gso, $postbody);
```

By inspecting `$gso` ContentType is being added but in the cloud console is added with the default `application/octet-stream` type.

Is there another way to set the content type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
$postbody = array('mimeType' => 'image/jpeg', "data" => $imgData);
$gso = new Google_StorageObject();

$gso->setName($imageName);
$resp = $objects->insert('bucket-name', $gso, $postbody);
```

It seems 'mimeType' its a parameter.
Take a look at line 39 in https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/tags/0.6.7/src/service/Google_ServiceResource.php

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a bug. I'd suggest filing it with google-api-php-client.

In the meanwhile, there is a workaround. Google Cloud Storage treats the Content Type like any other metadata. You can change the content type of an object after you upload it by by using the `$objects->update()` method.

Comment: The update method throws this exception "Uncaught exception 'Google_Exception' with message '(update) unknown parameter: 'Content-Type'"

Comment: The content type isn't a parameter to the update call. It's a field in the JSON body of the message with the name "contentType".