# Google cloud storage wrong file type

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload an image to a bucket in Google Cloud Storage via PHP (my server code handles the upload to Google)

The file is uploaded OK, but the Type (when looking in the browser) is `application/octet-stream`

Where is my mistake?

```
$data = file_get_contents('<local file path>.jpg');
$gso = new Google_Service_Storage_StorageObject();
$gso->setName("test8.jpg");
$gso->setContentType('image/jpeg');
$postbody = array('uploadType' => 'multipart', 'data' => $data);
$ret = $service->objects->insert($user_bucket, $gso, $postbody);
```

Comment: This has been answered and verified here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060445/cant-set-content-type-to-google-storage-with-the-google-php-client